# How to show full images with no errors in after effects?

Tags: after-effects, windows-media-encoder

I am trying to open my project and render it on another PC (my cousin's PC), but 2 of the images don't appear fully, but look like a TV with no signal.

This is a screenshot to see what is happening:

[image: enter image descripti on here]

- I tried to search for missing files or misspelled files in order to replace them but there was none, I also tried to use media encoder to render but nothing.
- I also tried to use GPU in preferences

Can you please solve this problem for me?

Answer (score 0):

The TV signal image indicates that a file is missing.

Try copying the image file onto your other PC and then drag it into the root folder in After Effects.

Also, clear your media cache to delete any old references to file locations